# when i used cargo maven plugin,execute mvn cargo:start ,print error,what is wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0:start (default-cli) on project project: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0:start failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [Tomcat6x], type = [installed]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide the command you have typed on command line and mvn file contents.

Comment: command is "mvn cargo:start"

Comment: the pom.xml is too long,i can not upload.